# Basic for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, minimum

I have a simple question in Matlab. How can I creat a for loop that will choose the value from a vector for which the result is smallest and write the chosen value from vector into .txt file? For example , if I have:

```
T = 100;
W = 20;
h = [h1 h2 h3 ... ];
y = 2*T*W/h;
```

I want to create loop that will search vector h for a value that will provide minimum value of y and write the chosen h into .txt file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For loop:

```
min_y = 2*T*W/h(1);
h_chosen = 1;
for i = 2:length(h)
  if min_y > 2*T*W/h(i)
    min_y = 2*T*W/h(i);
    h_chosen = i;
  end
end
```

Much faster than for-loop:

```
[~, idx] = min(arrayfun(@(i) 2*T*W/h(i), 1:length(h)));
h_chosen = h(idx);
```

Write to `.txt` file: (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)

```
fileID = fopen('min_h.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID, '%d\n', h_chosen);
```

Comment: Hey @scmg thank you for your answer, but instead of position I want to write exact value of h_chosen. And my second question is if can this be done with simulink model inside for loop -  to loop simulation for every value of h and dependigly on result of simulation to choose and display/write value of h that provides minimal result ? Thanks again!!

Comment: did you try the code? `h_chosen = h(idx)` gives you the value of `h_chosen` ... about simulink model, i'm not sure, you can try, or at least post some examples ...

Comment: Why the `arrayfun`? You could just use `min(2*T*W./h)`

Comment: @scmg here is my simulink model (postimg.org/image/45ove70qz/86687f75), I want to run simulation for h = [h1 h2 h3 h4 .. ] and to write/disp h that provides smallest m_fuel ( W and T are constant values, they are not changing ).